# Android changing theme with user Preference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-theme

I want to change the theme of my app with the preference of the user.

I've searched for it already but all tutorials and answers we're about changing the theme statically (e.g setTheme(R.style.Light)).

But i want the theme to be applied dynamically (eg. User chooses Theme "Dark" in the Settings -> Theme "Dark" is applied in the activity).
I'm sorry that i haven't posted some code, but i haven't achieved any good solution for now, i will post some code when i get some.

Can anybody post me some code or thoughts about how to achieve this?

I'm sorry for this elementary question, but this really freaks me out.
Thank you.

Comment: Please provide more details. Where do you want to put that theme settings in your app, and how do you want it to react. Also try to post some of your code...

Comment: I want to put an listview with the available themes in the settings and to set that chosen theme as theme for the MainActivity, probably with a sharepreference changelistener

Comment: Is your settings a normal activity or you use preference screen?

Comment: I use preferencescreen